# Facing problems in dividing numbers in SAS

Tags: sas, floating-point-precision

I am trying perform mathematical operation on numeric variables in SAS. However i am facing some issues. Following is the attributes of columns

```
 val=col1/(col1*fact1+col2*fact2 +col3*fact3)
```

The informats for all the columns is best32. and the format is best 12. and the length is 8. All the variables have floating point values like 0.33092222

I get missing values in val when i perform the above operation. I do not understand how.

Comment: Show us the code, sample input and sample output, please.

Comment: Are any of the values missing?  If a single one of those six columns has a missing value there, the result would be missing.

Comment: None of the values are missing. All of the six columns have decimal values

Comment: Does anything interesting get written out to the log?

Comment: Similar to what @Joe said regarding missing values, if the denominator is 0, i.e. `col1*fact1 + col2*fact2 + col3*fact3 = 0`, then the result will be missing. Division by 0 results in missing in SAS.